# jQuery AutoComplete with three levels of suggestions?

Tags: javascript, django, jquery-autocomplete

I am building a django based application and its time to add the DHTML stuff.

One of my fields represent a database field with this format databaseName.tableName.fieldName

I would like to have javascript autocompletion in three levels, say once I type part of the database names I get a list of all matching databases, one that is selected I get a list of all tables, and once that is selected I get a list of all fields in that table, all in the same textfield.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

managed to do with jquery.autocomplete (multiple: true) option.